# How to install Grails fields plugin scaffolding templates

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am using Grails 3.0.4. The fields plugin documentation states that the scaffolding templates can be installed using the command "grails install-form-fields-templates".

How ever is Grails 3.0.4 there is no install-form-field-templates command which can be used not the Grails console.

Does any one know how to install fields plugin scaffolding templates in Grails 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filed an issue in Grails Fields plugin. Got a response from them that the command to use is Grails install templates. This just installs the scaffolding templates. For more info, pls browse https://github.com/grails3-plugins/fields/issues/14

Comment: Looks like the "fields" project in github was forked, so the link is broken. The corrected link is https://github.com/grails-fields-plugin/grails-fields/issues/14

Answer (score 0):

It's actually grails install-templates.  The hyphen is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the command "grails install-templates" does not create the templates to be used by the fields plugin. For example: The template _wrapper.gsp (v.1.5 onwards) or _field.gsp (before v.1.5) which should be found in grails-app/views/_fields/default/_wrapper.gsp is not created. And it is up to the developer to infer how it should be structured.This is a bit inconvenient.